# How do I know what iTunes credit is for?

Tags: itunes, itunes-store

So I have "2 Credits" showing on the top right of the iTunes Store screen. I've purchased music, but that hasn't changed the number of credits. Are the credits specifically to be used for certain items, if so how do I know what items?

[image: iTunes screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

From https://discussions.apple.com/message/11510256#11510256

> It means that your next two purchases of that type won't be charged to a credit card or count against a gift card balance. They are sometimes granted by the iTunes Store staff.

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot]
From https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20100207142341AA3Kh6k

> It means you can get one[in your case 2] song download using that credit.

Screenshot:

[image]

From http://forums.macrumors.com/threads/itunes-is-displaying-5-credits-next-to-my-email-address-in-store-what-does-it-mean.1478823/

> 5[in your case 2] free downloads. Did you report any problems with a purchase to them recently? They give them out for that kind of thing sometimes.

Screenshot:
[image: screenshot]

Comment: This does not tell me how I know what I can use them for... do I just have to go buy every type of media to figure it out?

Comment: @CharlesJohnThompsonIII Try clicking on it. What does it say then?

Comment: Nothing, it's not a button.

Comment: Re: your edit, no it does not mean I can get one song. As I said in the details of my question, I've tried purchasing songs from the iTunes Store and it charges my card, the number of credits does not change.

Answer (score 1):

I clicked on Account at the bottom of the page and it took me to a page and under Apple ID Summary, it says Apple ID Balance: 1 Movie Rental.
I think this credit is only good for rental maybe?